# How can I detect when an Electron window is being copied from? Having trouble intercepting the WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE message

Tags: windows, .net-core, electron

I want to detect when the user has copied from a window.

To intercept the [`WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/wm-clipboardupdate) message, I have to first register the window to receive the message via the [`AddClipboardFormatListener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-addclipboardformatlistener).

The docs say:

> When a window has been added to the clipboard format listener list, it is posted a `WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE` message whenever the contents of the clipboard have changed.

My Electron app is doing just this.

main.js:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

app.whenReady().then(async () => {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow();
  await mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

  mainWindow.webContents.on("did-create-window", (window, details) => {
    const handle = Array.from(window.getNativeWindowHandle());
    // await sending handle to a .NET process to register the window with the clipboard thing as per the Remarks section in the docs below
    const WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE= 0x031D; // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/wm-clipboardupdate
    window.hookWindowMessage(WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE, (wp, lp) =>
    {
          console.log(wp);
     });
  });
})

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  app.quit();
})
```

index.html

```
<button onclick="window.open('https://google.com')">Open Window</button>
```

And my .NET process is doing this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static void RegisterWindowWithClipboard(byte[] hwndBuffer) {
    if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) {
        Array.Reverse(hwndBuffer);
    }

    IntPtr winHandle;
    if (hwndBuffer.Length == 4) winHandle = (IntPtr)BitConverter.ToUInt32(hwndBuffer, 0);
    else winHandle = (IntPtr)BitConverter.ToUInt64(hwndBuffer, 0);

    AddClipboardFormatListener(winHandle);
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool AddClipboardFormatListener(IntPtr hwnd);
```

However, when I open a window and copy stuff in it, the `hookWindowMessage` callback never gets triggered. Why would this be? Am I registering the window wrong, or does it need to be registered in the same process as what created the window?

`AddClipboardFormatListener` is returning `true`, which suggests it successfully registered the window.

I posted a github issue [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/31173) and one of the developers suggested this might be an Electron issue, but it seemed from her response that she was just saying that Electron needed to call `AddClipboardFormatListener`, which I'm doing.

Why is this not working?

Comment: Only the window interested in the clipboard change notification should be doing this, the window from which data is being copied doesn't need to do anything special, just place data on the clipboard in the usual way.

Comment: So, do you want to detect when an Electron window is copied from, or do you want an Electron window to detect when the user copies anything anywhere?

Comment: @BenVoigt I want to detect when an Electron window is copied from.

Comment: And this is your Electron app?  Just catch `WM_COPY` in your main message loop before `DispatchMessage` is called.  Before you ask, no I don't know how to control the main loop of Electron. In C# you would call `Application.AddMessageFilter()`

Comment: @BenVoigt Yeah, this is my Electron app. Yeah I'm not totally sure how to do that. I tried hooking that message via the electron `hookWindowMessage` API, but to no avail. I might need to rely on Electron changes

Comment: "I tried hooking that message" Which message are you talking about?  Your question is all about `WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE` which is the wrong message for the job.  That one is for knowing when some other application copies to the clipboard, so you can for example enable or disable your "Paste" toolbar button properly.  It has nothing to do with copy operations in your own application.

Comment: @BenVoigt I was talking about the `WM_COPY` message

Comment: My guess is that you hooked `WM_COPY` in the wrong window.  My suggestion was to process it at the main message loop where messages for all windows are seen.  It's also possible that Electron goes directly from accelerator and/or menu processing to clipboard without using the `WM_COPY` message.

Comment: @BenVoigt In a legacy app which I'm migrating to a new tech, we also hook `WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE`, which makes me think that maybe that *is* what I want, and I just didn't explain myself correctly.

To clarify, I want to detect when a user copies content from Electron windows (and then I'll detect what window they're pasting into and block them in some cases). Is `WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE` the wrong message for the job?

Comment: "I'll detect what window they're pasting into"... you cannot do this at the time of copy at all, this requires significant changes to your clipboard support.  You'd need to place a data provider object on the clipboard instead of the data itself, then DCOM is used to call a function on your data provider *when the paste operation occurs*.  Or you can use ["delayed rendering"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/clipboard-operations#delayed-rendering), which uses `WM_RENDERFORMAT` instead of a DCOM method call.  This is the only way to make a decision at paste time.

Comment: For the object-oriented approach to delayed rendering, see [`OleSetClipboard `](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ole2/nf-ole2-olesetclipboard) and [`IDataObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-idataobject)

Comment: @BenVoigt, well actually, I would just intercept the `paste` event from the webpage that's in the window (I control this), and cancel it if we determined that we last copied from a window whose content shouldn't be pasted into the page.

Comment: So you don't care about pasting into other applications on the computer?  If user wants to paste the data into the webpage they can copy from your sensitive data, paste to Notepad, copy from Notepad, paste to the web, and your restrictions won't do anything about that.

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't care about that in this particular case. It's not so much that this data is sensitive, but that it only applies to certain contexts, and it would be bad if it were pasted into another window that's for a different context.

Comment: Is your code putting the data on the clipboard or is that happening deep in some third-party library?  If your code is doing it, then you could use a registered clipboard format to store, alongside the text itself, information about the context.  And in the paste operation, query for that format and check the context before obtaining the text.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm not totally following - you're asking if I control what's going on the clipboard? Not really. The Ctrl+C operation is just using the default OS behavior and copying whatever is selected. I was going to handle it a little differently. I don't necessarily want other stuff on the clipboard in case they want to paste the data in another application, but it's a good idea